# Using MadBee android bridge to get list of connected devices

Tags: c#, android, adb

I am developing a small application and using this project as a framework for accessing devices through socket to adb:

http://madb.codeplex.com

My code in constructor of main form:

```
if (useMadBee())
        {
            BridgeContainer.manager.adb.
                DeviceChanged += new EventHandler<DeviceEventArgs>(beeDeviceChanged);
            BridgeContainer.manager.adb.
                DeviceConnected += new EventHandler<DeviceEventArgs>(beeDeviceConnected);
            BridgeContainer.manager.adb.
                DeviceDisconnected += new EventHandler<DeviceEventArgs>(
                    beeDeviceDisconnected);
        }
```

where adb is AndroidDebugBruidge (class from MadBee)

This is one of my EventHandlers:

```
public void beeDeviceConnected(object sender, DeviceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((string)dev_con_synclock).Equals("y"))
        {
            dev_con_synclock = "n";
            lock (dev_con_synclock)
            {
                List<Device> lista = BridgeContainer.manager.adb.Devices;
                connectedDevices.Clear();
                this.toolStripComboDevices.Items.Clear();

                foreach (Device d in lista)
                {
                    AndroidDevice newDevice = new AndroidDevice();
                    newDevice.modelName = d.Properties["ro.build.product"].ToString();
                    newDevice.deviceSerialNumber = d.SerialNumber;
                    this.toolStripComboDevices.Items.Add(
                    newDevice.modelName + "(" + newDevice.deviceSerialNumber + ")");
                    connectedDevices.Add(newDevice);
                }

                if (connectedDevices.Count > 0)
                {
                    toolStripComboDevices.Text = toolStripComboDevices.Items[0].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    toolStripComboDevices.Text = "";
                }
            }
            dev_con_synclock = "y";
        }
    }
```

And around the line

```
List<Device> lista = BridgeContainer.manager.adb.Devices;
```

methods stops executions, program continues to live. When I debug on this line, I can see that in that line method everything goes fine (I am getting collection of devices), and suddenly program goes to DeviceMonitorLoop in MadB class DeviceMonitor and finishes on couple of loops.

Block **foreach (Device d in lista)** in my program is never executed, for some strange reason the method won't continue to execute

what I am doing wrong ?

I can easily get list of device on program start, but when event is executed (i.e. device disconnected) (btw. I don't know why its executed 3 times), my method won't work

is it possible for the method beeDeviceConnected(object sender, DeviceEventArgs e) to be cancelled by other thread ?

Comment: The Devices property is not currently functioning correctly off the AndroidDebugBridge. I am fixing it so it will work. The issue is with the DeviceMonitor not functioning properly. As a workaround, you can use the AdbHelper.GetDevices method. - See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697068/accessing-android-devices-in-c-sharp) for more info.