# Accessing android devices in C#

Tags: c#, android, .net, adb, madbee

I am using MAD-Bee(Managed ADB) library to access ADB in C#. I am just trying to get list of devices attached to PC. I am getting list of devices properly when I use ADB from command prompt, but I get 0 in my C# form.
Here's the code I've tried -

```
    AndroidDebugBridge mADB;
    String mAdbPath;
    IList<Device> mDeviceList = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mAdbPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_ROOT");
        mADB = AndroidDebugBridge.CreateBridge(mAdbPath + "\\platform-tools\\adb.exe", true);
        mADB.Start();

        var list = mADB.Devices;
        Console.WriteLine(""+list.Count);
    }
```

The problem is MAD-bee doesn't have any proper documentation or guide on how to start with it. Any help in this?

Comment: I want to point out, eventually, what you have will work. But currently AndroidDebugBridge.Devices depends on the DeviceMonitor, which is not functional in its current state. I have filed this as [an issue](https://madb.codeplex.com/workitem/21255) and will change it to use the "currently working way" of getting a list of devices.

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an issue. I'd love to see this library developed further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Woops found it now -

```
List<Device> devices = AdbHelper.Instance.GetDevices ( AndroidDebugBridge.SocketAddress );
```

More information is available in these tests -

[`MadBee Tests`](https://madb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1423061)

Comment: Currently the Tests are the best place to look for examples. I still have a bunch of work to do on this project but I work on it in my free time and don't have much of it. I am the only active developer, and I use the term "active" loosely. There should be tests for most of the functionality. I just happen to stumble across this question, otherwise I would have answered it.

Comment: I am using the library for one of my pet project for making a development tool for Android developers. I made few modifications in the source myself and would love to share them as soon as I could polish them properly. Thanks for developing this. You rock :-)

Comment: Thanks for this i'm looking for a C# lib myself at the moment!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest you use another library in C# for your application.

I found AndroidLib.dll on XDA which has provided a way of interfacing my C# application.

The Thread can be found here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1512685

He has a GITHUB for the source and in the GITHUB he has example projects in Visual Studio solutions files to learn from as well as detailed usage.